# bxslider goToPrevSlide

Tags: jquery, slider, bxslider

I am having an issue with bxslider and the method 'goToPrevSlide'..it's weird because 'goToNextSlide' is working just fine as you can see in this fiddle:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5HunP/2/)

the previous and next link are within each slide as you can see.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var slider = $('.slide').bxSlider({
      mode: 'horizontal',
      controls: false,
      pager: false,
      autoControls: false,
      randomStart: false,
      auto: false,
      autoStart: false,
    });

    $('#next').click(function () {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        return false;
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        slider.goToPrevSlide();
        return false;
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<ul class="slide">
    <li>
        <div class="slide1">
            <a id="next" href="#">next</a>
        </div>
     </li>
    <li>
      <div class="slide2">
            <a id="prev" href="#">prev</a>
        </div>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
    width: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
    background-color: blue;
    height:300px;
}

.slide2 {
    background-color: red;
    height:300px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Priya_1993/5HunP/15/

hope this solves your problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var slider = $('.slide').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
    });

    $('#next').click(function () {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        return false;
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        slider.goToPrevSlide();
        return false;
    });
})
```